# VSCode can't change Java Version in "Configure Java Runtime"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Im trying to configure a Java Web project in VSCode and want to use Java 8 for a project.

[Configure Java Classpath Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpGmJ.png)

The value "Java Version" is set to 19 and i can select other versions but it wont ever get saved. If i press CTRL+S or press the pen button next to the selection, nothing happens. If i come back to this screen after changing it its back to version 19 (which i dont want).

Is there another way to change this setting or am i doing something wrong?

I installed the Java Extensions Pack already.

Answer (score 0):

If you [follow this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-jdk) you should find some helpful information. VSC supports Java versions 1.5 and above

If I could give my two cents however, there are many IDEs that are much more intuitive and have built-in Java support where VSC does not. IDEs like IntelliJ or Eclipse are your best options for debugging, maven, library support, etc. (IntelliJ is my personal favourite).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to make sure that the corresponding version of jdk is installed on your machine. and then select it in the **Configure Java Runtime** interface. It can also be configured in the **settings.json** file.

```json
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-16",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-16.0.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.3.7-hotspot"
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-18",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-18.0.1.1",
            "default": true
        }
    ]
```

It should be noted that if your project uses a build tool, then you need to modify the Java version in the corresponding configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been struggling to get VSCode to use the JDK version I want. In my case I am using gradle build tools, and these are picking up the correct JDK from my JAVA_HOME environment variable. But the Java extension for VSCode still picked up JDK17 and was using this for debugging. I tried many things suggested on Stack Overflow and other forums, including adding the following in my settings.json

> "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "C:/Program Files/Semeru/jdk-11.0.20.101-openj9",

But VSCode still stubbornly picked up Semeru JDK 17 (also installed on my PC). Finally I found the setting which fixed this. I edited the registry and removed the keys for 17 under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK\ (all of which contained paths to JDK 17 versions no longer on my computer). I then added the following keys:

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK\11
> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK\11.0.20.101

In each of these keys, create the item

> JavaHome = C:\Program Files\Semeru\jdk-11.0.20.101-openj9

To be sure you get this right, you can rename the 17 key to 11, and change the JavaHome path value under that key, rather than deleting the old key and then recreating it.

Now VSCode picks this JDK 11 when I reopen my workspace, and uses this JDK for the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac and VSCode Version: 1.86.2 I was unable to select an alternative JDK for my Java project. In particular I wanted to run my Java classes with a specific JDK.

I tried to add the JDK to the settings.json file ( with both a  "java.jdt.ls.java.home" entry and a entry with  "java.configuration.runtimes" but VSCode always run the wrong JDK. Even if setting proper JAVA_HOME before starting VSCode did not help.

Eventually I modified the launch.json file by adding a `javaexec` entry and then I could control what JDK to use! Below I pinpoint my JDK 21 installed using homebrew;

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "MyJavaClass",
        "javaExec": "/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "se.myorg.MyJavaClass",
        "projectName": "myproject"
    }]
}
```